# MikroTik: bisschoff load balancing problem?

Tags: router, failover, pppoe, load-balancing

I'm using [bisschoff load-balancing](http://mum.mikrotik.com/presentations/ZA13/bisschoff.pdf) .its really good and works fine.but it has a problem. The problem is when a adsl line don't have access to internet , it don't disable automatically and vice versa. For that i statically disable and enable lines. Is there any solution about this ? 
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the routerOS netwatch tool to monitor each ADSL's gateway. When netwatch detects a failure (=no more ping), you can execute a script to disable some rules, and another to re-enable them when the ping gets back.

Comment: Thanks.Could you help me more and write script and netwatch ? Note : I have 4 PPPOE clients in mikrotik .